# replace packets of a connection

Tags: delphi, connection, replace, packet, packets

How to replace a string in packets of a connection?
I use Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

search [this topic](http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?t=90&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0&sid=a3319628d969c61c2e981314d7743f92) for appsniff(wiht source), it hooks various winsock functions and output the ongoing and incoming packets. inside the hooker function you can change packets before pass it to real winsock functions .  but this is very complicated task, it can easly crash applications and produce BSOD.